# Clarification of solution to question. Linear algebra matrix factorization.

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

So I am having trouble understanding why the matrices commute specifically how we go from $A(VV^{-1})$ to $V \Lambda V^{-1}$.

Note I'm not sure how to write the A without the middle bit in latex.

Can anyone clarify this for me?

Comment: But don't we need to show that $A = V \Lambda V^T$, just using it as a definition doesn't show it?

Comment: Actually, I can't put this into a sensible post. It appears what you have is from the solution section, or solution manual, of some book, where the original question is elsewhere.  They are discussing a standard result, given a symmetric real matrix $A,$ there is an orthonormal matrix $P,$ meaning $PP^T = P^T P = I,$ such that $P^T A P = D$ is diagonal.

Comment: This is from my Tutorial for linear models, it's the question and answer.